Multiple instances of same Entity
As far as I know JPA manages all the entities in the persistent context when entities get created. Will there be multiple instances of same entity? Suppose there are 2 methods being called at same time which creates same entity then will there be 2 instances of same entity created in persistent context and any changes done to them will be in respective instance?

please define "the same entity"

No no actually my question is can persistent context can have multiple instances of same entity? If yes then how it's uniquely identified. I mean related to transaction

If you add multiple entities with the same id to the context, the changes made to any entity will reflect to all of them.
However, hibernate will optimize the process in such a manner that as few as possible database calls are made.
If there are multiple entities in the context that share the same fields but not the id, changes made to an instance of an entity will not reflect to other entities.

Thank you so much !! Also wanted to know what is difference between persistent context and persistent units

The persistence context manages persistence units.
I suggest you watch Laur Spilca's hibernate fundamentals playlist
